# merging Google Analytics data after subsite namechange

Tags: google-analytics

We have been using Google Analytics for several years. About a year ago, we moved our blog from blog.oursite.com to oursite.com/blog. Overall, great move. But now there is now way to compare blog analytics prior to the changeover with the older data.

Is there a simple way around this? Some way to set up a profile for the blog that includes both subdomains (well, subdomain + domain)?